# Forearm posture prediction based on arm and hand angles

Tags: unity-game-engine, neural-network, sensors

I have 2 sensors: on an upper arm and on a hand, each gives me a quaternion (or Euler angles) of its position in global 3d space, do you have any ideas, how can I find the forearm position?
For example, I need this value to solve the issue:
when I hold my hand on a table and move up my upper arm (like a wing), the program thinks that I move my hand up together with the upper arm.

Comment: This is pretty broad (too broad for Stack Overflow), but it sounds like an inverse kinematics problem. Perhaps try reading up on the theory behind IK solvers (it takes a bit of math to implement your own, so it may be worth looking at existing ones that work with Unity).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Sure, I've expanded on it a bunch and added it as an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe sounds like an [inverse kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) problem. In effect, this is the way of determining the required angles (and by extension, positioning) of intermediate joints in a limb (or other jointed object) based on the desired position of its free end (the *end effector*).

Rather than tackling this difficult mathematics question on your own, you may want to look at [Unity's own inverse kinematics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) implementation. However, this might not be feasible if you can't adapt your in-game object(s) to an `Animator`.

You could also code a solution on your own. Creating a generic solution to this problem is extremely mathematically complex - but you've got some extra information available to you: the actual angle and positioning of the hand and upper arm. If you specify either the forearm length or upper arm length (you can even derive this mathematically, up to you!), then some light linear algebra should be enough for your purposes (provided your sensor readings are correct).

If you specify a forearm length FL, then you need to find the point of intersection (the elbow) along the upper arm's direction vector which is distance FL from the hand. Alternatively, if you specify an upper arm length UL, you just need to move UL/2 down the upper arm's direction vector (since the position is in the middle of the upper arm) to get the elbow position.

In both cases, once you have the elbow position, it's trivial to get the forearm position and angle. Here's a diagram for visualization of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do not know length of the arm. This is one of the problems, which I need to solve

Comment: @KhanSuleyman It's a little more complicated if you can't estimate any lengths, but not impossible - that's why I suggested you can also derive the lengths mathematically, by using a common upper arm to forearm length ratio (like one [listed here](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2006/bodyproportions.shtml)). Based on the ratio, you just need to solve an equation for the lengths of the two arm parts that satisfy the given ratio, and the given angling. (It is a bit math-heavy, so some reading on linear algebra could be necessary.)

Comment: Your answer is very valuable, it helps me a lot. Also I want to use machine learning (or deep learning) methods, what do you think about it?

Comment: I have some issues. I do not have any positions, only angles of rotation of the upper-arm sensor. I need to create virtual forearm sensor to find a position of the palm. I do not have a forearm sensor, that's why the computer thinks that palm does not stay on the table and moves up with the upper-arm.

Comment: @KhanSuleyman To clarify...how much information is available to you? Only a single angle? With so little information, you'll have to start making up assumptions because there isn't enough to extrapolate from. (And regarding the machine learning, I'm afraid that's outside of my domain. If you have a specific question regarding it, you'll need to make a new SO question.)

Comment: I have all information about the sensor's rotation. Rotation in 3-D space, rotation around its axis. Rotation around the sensor's initial position.

Comment: @KhanSuleyman Hmm...going with only those two rotations, and no positional information, I feel it may not be possible to explicitly calculate the forearm position. If you don't have more sensors available, is it possible to use the hand sensor on the forearm instead? Having hand rotation (and not wrist angle) isn't terribly useful for getting information on the rest of the arm, but if you have upper and forearm rotations, you can estimate the position of the hand.

Comment: @KhanSuleyman Although, when you say "rotation around its axis", are you talking about local rotation? As in...for the hand, that would give wrist rotation? (Rotation of hand relative to forearm?) That could change things.

Comment: The main task is to find the best position of the hand to visualize it in Unity according to the upperarm and the hand sensors. Rotation on its axis -   like the Earth rotates on its axis. We can have information about rotation around every axis. You know, which posture your hand have but do not know where it is exactly, but can find approximate position using rotation. I need to find the best position of the hand.

Comment: @KhanSuleyman If you make the assumption that the hand is fairly straight relative to the forearm, you can potentially treat the hand rotation as the forearm rotation as well, then determine its position using a mathematically-determined forearm length (using an arbitrary upper arm length). If this isn't a valid assumption, then I'd like to read the assignment text myself (unless what you quoted was the full text).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to solve the problem with this assummption.